# QueryException in Connection.php line 673:

Tags: php, mysql

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sp.sign_ups' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `sign_ups` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `user_name`, `password`, `re_password`, `contact`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (hassan, Mehedi, hassanmehedi@gmail.com, marlin, marlin, marlin, 01670654878, 2016-05-15 06:39:07, 2016-05-15 06:39:07))

I am facing above problem while clicking on submit button for sending sign up form data to database.

Here says 'Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sp.sign_ups' doesn't exist'.
But in my 'sp' named database doesn't have any kind of table named 'sign_ups'. It named 'sign_up'......

Already I dropped the 'sign_up' table once and recreated it.
Also restart the 'Apache' and 'MySQL' server. But nothing happened.

This is the controller SignUpController.php

```
<?php
```

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\sign_up;

class SignUpController extends Controller
{

```
public function showSignUp()
{
    return view('sign_up');
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    sign_up :: create(Request::all());
    return 'test';
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
```

}

This is Model sign_up.php

```
<?php
```

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class sign_up extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'user_name', 'password', 're_password', 'contact'];
}

Can anybody help ?

Comment: If you've recreated your `sign_ups` table, please confirm this table was in schema `sp`.

Comment: Will you please explain it @Reno ......

Comment: Hmm, `sp` is just the name of your database, you must confirm you've recreate this table in this database, not other. As usual, `Table 'sp.sign_ups' doesn't exist` this kind of error should be no table in your database or you've created your table in other database.

Comment: oh. @Reno then sign_up table is under the sp databse. I am sure about that. But you made a mistake that you told 'sp.sign_ups' but it is ' sp.sign_up '......that my prblem. I didn't make any table named ' sign_ups '.....mt table name is ' sign_up '......i didn't get it from where it came!!!

Comment: i guess you're using laravel as your framework. since I don't know laravel, can you tell me where did you configure the 'sign_up' view? and what is in the create() function?

Comment: yes @carmel you got it !!! It is laravel framework . Here 'sign_up' view is inside the 'view' folder which is also inside another folder called 'resource' and here create() inside the store() function will pass all data from the form to 'sign_up' Model..

Comment: @user5802196 What is in the create() function? can you post the code itself?  I ask because that is where something goes wrong.

Comment: Here create() can use to create a new php file in 'view' folder @carmel

Comment: @user5802196 There is only one place in the code that performs the insert to the database. I'm trying to help you locate that place. Somewhere in the why to that location the framework (or you) decides that the table name is 'sign_up'. you need to find that location. this is why I wanted to see what's in the create() function. it might be in the parent class 'Model'

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a typo in your code that creates the "insert into..." query.

double check it.

if you don't have a typo there then post your code here

Comment: There is no typo and i have checked it. Also upload Controller and Model code for your better understand @carmel

Answer (score 0):

In your sign_up.php Model you just need add $table property,

```
protected $table = "sign_up";
```

Update sign_up.php Model code should look like this,

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class sign_up extends Model {

protected $table = 'sign_up';

protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'user_name', 'password', 're_password', 'contact'];

 }
```